# Deleting rows from a table if it contains values from another table

Tags: powershell, csv

I am interning for a company and they tasked me with a challenge of finding rows in a table containing values from another table and delete them with Powershell and not using SQL. For example:

Product Table 1

```
    pName    | pCode | pPrice
Product 1.1  | 10001 |  3.99
Product 1.2  | 10007 |  5.49
Product 1.3  | 10009 |  3.00
```

Product Table 2

```
    pName    | pCode | pPrice
Product 2.1  | 10002 |  0.49
Product 2.2  | 10007 |  2.99
Product 2.3  | 10053 |  9.00
```

I need to remove the entire row of Product 2.2 from Table 2 since Table 1 contains its product code 10007.

I am thinking about creating a hash table, loop through each line in Table 2 and add them into this new hash table if they don't contain the same value found in Table 1, and finally export the hash table into a new csv file. My pseudo code:

```
$Output = @{}
$Table1 = IMPORT Table1.csv 
$Table2 = IMPORT Table2.csv

FOREACH ($Line in $Table2) {
   IF (!($Table1 -Contains $Table2[$Line]))
   $Output = Add-Content($Table2[$Line])
}

$Output | Export-Csv
```

However I am completely new to PowerShell and I don't know much about the syntaxes of it. Can anyone help me with a somewhat valid code? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it `pCode` the only column you need to correlate?

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` instead of `IMPORT`. Then: `$Output = $Table2 | Where-Object {$_.pCode -notin $Table1.pCode}`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes I only need to compare that specific column

Comment: @JosefZ provided the right answer to your question